# Проверка числа на четность

Tags: c++

Есть код, который представлен ниже. Нужно переделать его с использованием функции для проверки четности введенного числа. После проверки на четность, программа должна запрашивать еще числа для ввода.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    int a;
    cout << ("-Введите число:");
    cin >> a;
    if (a % 2 == 0)
    {
        cout << ("-Это чётное число \n");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ("-Это Нечётное число \n");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Так программа уже у вас есть, нужно только в цикл поставить и в нем спрашивать следующие числа, и если скажем введено слово `quit` выходить

Comment: @Rikitikitavi можно подробнее?) Или кусочек правильного кода куда вставить. Я новичек в этом, а нужно сделать очень быстро.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```
std::string str;
while (true)
{
    std::cout << ("-Введите число:");
    std::cin >> str;
    if (str == "quit")
        break;

    int value = ::strtol(str.c_str(), 0, 10);
    if (value % 2 == 0)
        std::cout << ("-чётное \n");
    else
        std::cout << ("-Нечётное \n");
}
```

Только здесь не обработана ситуация когда некорректная строка передается

Answer (score 3):

```
for(;;)
{
    int N;
    cout << "Введите число; 0 для завершения: ";
    if (!(cin >> N) || (N==0)) break;
    cout << N << " - " << ((N&1)? "не":"") << "четное число\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам бы добавить цикл

```
 for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) 
    {
    cout << ("-Введите число:");
    cin >> a;
    if (a % 2 == 0)
{
    cout << ("-Ето чётное число \n");
}
else
{
cout << ("-Ето Нечётное число \n");
}
    }
```

тогда цикл будет выполнять проверку 1000 раз, все зависит от того сколько и при каких условиях выполнять проверку на четность, а то может понадобиться другой цикл